# Silverlight WP7 resources dll

Tags: windows-phone-7, resources, assemblies

I need some help for my Windows Phone 7 application.

I would like in my first project to build a .dll which embed all my strings resources.

And then, in my second project, I would like to build HelloWorld Application, which can use strings from my .dll.

To do that I build .dll according to this post : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21a15yht%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

So i first compile .resx file :

```
ResGen.exe /useSourcePath /compile strings.fr.rex,HelloWorld.strings.fr.resources
```

Ok, my file **HelloWorld.strings.fr.resources** is successfully created.

Now, I compile the .resources file to .dll :

```
al.exe /t:lib /embed:HellowWorld.strings.fr.resources /culture:fr /out:HelloWorld.resources.dll
```

Ok, my file **HelloWorld.resources.dll** is successfully created.

Now, in my second project, WP7 HelloWorld, i do right click on "references" and add my .dll.

Thenk in main page I call resources manager like this :

```
System.Resources.ResourceManager rm = new System.Resources.ResourceManager("HelloWorld.resources", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

And try to load a string from dll :

```
PageTitle.Text = rm.GetString("mystring");
```

But at runtime I get exception : **MissingManifestResourceException**

Can you help to solve it ?

Comment: Does this solution help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/c-what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

I've been told in the App Hub forum that you can't do DLLs with WP7.
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/87635/525973.aspx#525973
This blows what I want to do out of the water because I have a big library of C code that I don't want to rewrite in C#. I have a ton of tables representing graphs and C# lacks decent a struct facility which C/C++ had implemented very well. That's progress?

It's bad enough that C# (which does have some interesting things) fails again to even implement a struct facility, a rudimentary macro facility and competent conditional compile facility, and now this. Can't reuse C code? I'm thinking of punting WP7 and going to Android and iPhone for my app. Grrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr.