# Resource File String Addition

Tags: c#, resources

I am working on a Multilingual Desktop Application. I created a resource file for it and added some strings. It works fine but now I want to add some more strings, and it fails with the following exception when I run the program.

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "Madrassa.String.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "TelicMadrassaProject" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.Method : Void HandleResourceStreamMissing(System.String)
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> at System.Resources.ManifestBasedResourceGroveler.HandleResourceStreamMissing(String fileName)

this exception is thrown even though the string name exist in the resource file.

Comment: DId you define the same string in the neutral culture resource file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to add a LogicalName element to the project definition. See 
[MissingManifestResourceException when running tests after building with MSBuild (.mresource has path in manifest)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080737/missingmanifestresourceexception-when-running-tests-after-building-with-msbuild) for more information.