# How to write DependentUpon clauses for C# files in subdirectories?

Tags: visual-studio, monodevelop, csproj

We are trying to get our C# application to compile and run with *both*

- Visual Studio 10 (with the Microsoft compiler), on Windows, and
- MonoDevelop with gmcs, on Linux

However, sections like this in the `.csproj` files (for Visual Studio):

```xml
<Compile Include="Foo\Bar.cs" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="Foo\Bar.resx">
    <DependentUpon>Bar.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

must be changed as follows before they will work with MonoDevelop/gmcs
(if not, at runtime, resources.GetObject() will throw a [MissingManifestResourceException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.missingmanifestresourceexception.aspx)):

```xml
<Compile Include="Foo\Bar.cs" />
<EmbeddedResource Include="Foo\Bar.resx">
    <DependentUpon>Foo\Bar.cs</DependentUpon>
</EmbeddedResource>
```

How to rewrite this into a form they will both accept?
(Short of deleting the `DependentUpon` element, of course.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meanwhile I have researched a couple of ways to deal with the situation.

For instance, [it is apparently possible](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fsharp-opensource/1YG5jt-XeKg/8a7dM0nWVtsJ) to add `Condition` attributes with the value `$(VisualStudioVersion) != ''` in order to make them conditional on whether Visual Studio is being used.

However, on a whim (after reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329631/17945)) I tried something entirely different: I replaced my nested namespaces

```
namespace Baz
{
    namespace Bar
    {
        [...]
    }
}
```

with dotted namespace notation:

```
namespace Baz.Bar
{
    [...]
}
```

and *voilà*, the `MissingManifestResourceException` no longer exists, even with the original `DependentUpon` clause.

Problem solved, but I don't know why.