# Instantiating a new type with MEF

Tags: wpf, mef, prism-4

I am using `CompositionInitializer.SatisfyImports(this)` from [Glen Block](https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=f8b2fd72406fb218&id=F8B2FD72406FB218!238) with a WPF application using Prism 4.1 and Prism's MEFExtensions.

I have used this many times before and not had a problem, but every once in a while when I call `SatisfyImports(this)` and get the following error:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll
>        Additional information: Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.   Make sure
>   "System.ComponentModel.Composition.Initialization.Strings.resources"
>   was correctly embedded or linked into  assembly
>   "Microsoft.ComponentModel.Composition.Initialization.Desktop" at
>   compile time, or that all the satellite  assemblies required are
>   loadable and fully signed.
>        If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Anyone know why I'm getting this error and how to fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: What does MissingManifestResourceException mean and how to fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/c-what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: @AdiLester This is not the solution to this particular problem.  It is an error generated from MEF, and while the error itself seems similar, the solution in the other question does not work.

Answer (score 0):

The CompositionInitializer approach doesn't work with WPF in some cases, as evidenced by the MissingManifestResourceException above- basically, I think this is saying that one of the imports is failing due to some resource problem of the imported DLL... which you may or may not have any control over.

The better approach (I think) is to use the [MEF ExportFactory](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=PartCreator) to instantiate objects for WPF applications rather than the CompositionInitializer:

```
[Export]
public class OrderController {

  [Import] 
  public ExportFactory<OrderViewModel> OrderVMFactory {get;set;}

  public OrderViewModel CreateOrder() {
    return OrderVMFactory.CreateExport().Value;
  }
}
```

Worked for me anyways.

I do have some questions about memory management and the export factory, but that's another post :)