# How to use .resx resource files in C#.net?

Tags: c#, .net, internationalization, resources, resourcemanager

I would like to use resource files to internationalize my .net application. I'm trying a little test on a field of my Login page :

```
 <td class="libelleCnx" id="texteMdp" runat="server">

 Mot de passe :</td>
```

I created the resource file with visual studio, it's in App_LocalData, it's named Login.resx and contains the follwing resource :

```
 <data name="texteMotDePasse" xml:space="preserve">

 <value>Ze password</value>

 </data>
```

In my Login class, I try to use that resource like this:

```
 protected ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager("Login", typeof(Login).Assembly);

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

 {
 ...
 texteMdp.InnerText = manager.GetString("Login.texteMotDePasse");
 ...
 }
```

But I get a System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException when trying to access my Login page...

I can modify the field with "texteMdp.InnerText = "stuff" " so I guess the problem is not with the field. I think that the Resource File is not detected... Anyone has an idea why ?

Thank you !

Comment: Check this question, may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/c-what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it

Comment: ResourceManager reads *compiled* .resx files, the ones that are converted to binary .resources files by resgen.exe and get embedded in the assembly manifest.  Surely you missed a step somewhere :)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that ! Is resgen a fonction of Visual Studio ? Didn't see something else to do with the files, I'll look more carefully

Comment: So, I compiled the my file with resgen.exe, but now my web page is not found (I don't get the exception). It "works" again if I delete the compiled file. I guess that I have to embed it in an assembly to make it work, but I tried the al commande ("al file /out:Login.dll") but I get an AL 1047 error: error importing the file '...' -- 0x8013110e. How do I put my ressource in a satellite ?

Comment: In the end, Hans Passant solution worked, you just have to compile it with resgen.exe. My later problem is only because apparently there can't be a ressource.resource and a resource.resx file in the place, or else you get an error. (after my last comment, I tried deleting the resx file instead of the resource and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

you can use directly resourseName.StringName for example:

```
Login.texteMotDePasse
```

Comment: I read that somewhere to, but it didn't work :s. Maybe it's a matter of version of Visual Studio ? I work on 2005. Or does what Hans Passant commented above applies to that technique to ?