# "Unable to find assembly" after two successful finds

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, resources

I think my problem is similar to this:
[Missing Manifest Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/c-what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it)

However, not quite.
In my situation, when one clicks on the connect button (if no connection has been made), a form pops up, and you choose to which database you want to connect. Clicking on the connect button again, disconnects you from that connection. This can be repeated another time, but after disconnecting for the second time, and reconnecting for the third time, suddenly an error is thrown at this line:

`this.Icon = ((System.Drawing.Icon)(resources.GetObject("$this.Icon")));`

in the form's InitializeComponent() method, and it says, "Unable to find assembly S.V.G.resources". Now the form that causes the problem is in S.V.G.Config (with its own resx and designer) and my Resources.resx in S.V.G.Properties. There is a folder Resources that contains a bunch of images that are used by other folders with forms in the project.

So I don't know why this only happens the third time. I am assuming something doesn't get set back properly during the disconnects, but I don't know what to look for, and I inherited this code.

In the above link, I have tried solving my problem with "Run Custom Tool" to regenerate the Designer class in the Properties file.
I have tried to look for other class definitions in the form class in which the error is thrown, but seems like there aren't any. 
I have changed Resources from "Internal" (accessible only within the same class library) to "Public" (accessible from another class library), and no difference.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: You could try to run the [Fusion Log Viewer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to see if it gives some more helpful information about why it can't find the S.V.G.resources assembly.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the Fusion Log Viewer, but so far I haven't been able to get any closer to a solution. It doesn't seem to give enough detail. What are clues in the code that I could look for? New ResourceManager objects?

Comment: I haven't debugged a missing resource assembly, but when I'm trying to figure out other types of assemblies, Fusion will usually display the strong name (including version and public key) of the assembly it's trying to find. When you look at the Fusion logs, do you see the entry for the failed assembly? If so, does it display the strong name it's looking for and the locations it has checked?