# Missingmanifestresourseexeption in auto genereted code of ImageList

Tags: c#, winforms, imagelist

i have a problem with my autogenerated code in WinAplForm

On button click it should just open a new form with a treeView on it....this treeview uses an imageList, and now i got this error on initilisation:

in MyForm.Designer.cs file

> Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure
>   "WindowsFormsApplication2.MapForma.resources" was correctly embedded
>   or linked into assembly "WindowsFormsApplication2" at compile time, or
>   that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>   signed

in this line: (iltest is the name of the imagelist)

```
this.iltest.ImageStream = ((System.Windows.Forms.ImageListStreamer)(resources.GetObject("iltest.ImageStream")));
```

i checked out this topic, 
[C#: What does MissingManifestResourceException mean and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/c-what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it?answertab=votes#tab-top)

which is similar to mine, and i did the same thing, 
right-click the Resources.resx file in the Solution Explorer and click Run Custom Tool. This re-generates the auto-generated Resources.Designer.cs file.

and it didnt worked, i still have the same problem...any suggestions?

Comment: That is not what it is complaining about, there's something wrong with the MapForma.resx file.  Simplest way to fix it, usually, is to delete the ImageList with the designer and add it back.

Comment: tried it already, and didnt work...the problem is when i add an image to the imageList, then it throws that error....Hans Passant

Comment: Did you try to add the NameSpace? See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36950823/6201755