# Visual C# changing image on control gives exception

Tags: c#, image, winforms, plugins, picturebox

I am writing a plugin in C#, in which I have a user control with a `linklabel` on it that controls a form that shows up like a `tooltip` and a `picturebox` next to the label to show the status whether or not the form is visible or hidden.

I have two images that are added as resources by the book via the Visual Studio PludingResources Designer. (I tried setting the Persistence of the images both to Linked at compile time and to embedded to solve the problem.)

The rubber meets the road in the following code:

```
pictureBox1.Image = SubAsst.PluginResources.SubAsst_Enabled1;
```

When the code execution hits this line to display the image, I get the 
`System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException` exception. The exception reads:

> "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure "SubAsst.PluginResources.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "SubtitlingAssistant" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed."

I looked all over on msdn and everywhere else I could but I could not find a solution yet. Except, if I change the code to use the built-in system icons, that works:

```
pictureBox1.Image = System.Drawing.SystemIcons.Information.ToBitmap();
```

So that is my workaround so far. However I would like to use my custom images for the plugin.

I suspect that the API does not allow image resources to be used, but this is not documented. I guess this from the fact that an icon can be imported and is displayed on the default button for the plugin.

I would appreciate any advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like some resource file is missing, check these

MSDN links

[You may receive a "System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException" error message when you access the .resources file of the form at run time](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/318603)
[A System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException exception occurs when you try to access a localized resource](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/839861)

[C#: What does MissingManifestResourceException mean and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/c-what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: Wow, that was a good one, thanks, especially this specific answer to this seemingly different question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/c-what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it/25442140#25442140

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:

What was missing is the CustomToolNamespace in the properties box:
[image: Properties of PluginResources.resx]

- Build action: Embedded Resource
- Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy
- Custom Tool: ResXFileCodeGenerator
- Custom Tool Namespace: [myapplicationnamespace]

The namespace matches the NameSpace of my application. As soon as I set this and rebuilt the application, the error was gone and the image displayed.

Thanks for the link in Meysam Tolouee's answer, which lead to [this "off-topic" answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/c-what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it/25442140#25442140). Here it is definitely not off-topic, and I wish I found this earlier.

What a great tool this StackOwerflow is!