# How to create and use resources files in C# via Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

I've execute the instruction which locates [there](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/framework/resources/creating-resource-files-for-desktop-apps#resources-in-text-files)

I can get, execute and use .exe file as it shown there.

But when I trying debug this code

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Resources;

namespace Example
{
    public class Example
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("GreetingResources",
                                     typeof(Example).Assembly);
            Console.Write(rm.GetString("prompt"));
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(rm.GetString("greeting"), name);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

with my GreetingResources.resources file, I get `MissingManifestResourceException`.

I also choose "Embedded resource" option in GreetingResources.resources file properties, but it doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does MissingManifestResourceException mean and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: Getting the arguments for the ResourceManager constructor correct is quite a bit harder than seems necessary.  That's why C# has the Resource Designer so you don't have to get this right.  Project > Properties > Resources tab, click "Click here to create one".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to project properties in VS, and see what the 'default namespace' is for the project.  Then put that before the resource name, eg.

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("<default namespace>.GreetingResources",
                                 typeof(Example).Assembly);
```

If the resource file is also under a folder, include that, eg.

```
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("<default namespace>.<my resource folder>.GreetingResources",
                                 typeof(Example).Assembly);
```

Comment: @AlexeyPashnin you probably have the resource under a folder, include that too.