# How to Set Interaction Behavior from Code Behind in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, interaction

I have a behavior for Window as follows

```
<Window>
    <my:Notify x:Name="Not"/>
    <behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <behavior:RebuildBehavior Element="{Binding ElementName=Not}" />
    </behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
<Window>
```

now i want to write this code in code behind, so i used this code:

in Notify.cs (Loaded Event):

```
RebuildBehavior behavior = new RebuildBehavior();
behavior.Element = this;
Interaction.GetBehaviors(this).Add(behavior);
```

But my app crashes in the last line `Interaction.GetBehaviors(this).Add(behavior);`

> System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException: 'Could not find the
> resource "ExceptionStringTable.resources" among the resources "

Did I write the correct code?

UPDATE:
I moved codes to window.cs (Loaded event)

```
RebuildBehavior behavior = new RebuildBehavior();
behavior.Element = Notify.Instance;
Interaction.GetBehaviors(this).Add(behavior);
```

crash fixed but not working

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Similar code does work by my. It must be something in `RebuildBehavior` which you didn't post.

Comment: Have you checked all cases from [What does MissingManifestResourceException mean and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327692/what-does-missingmanifestresourceexception-mean-and-how-to-fix-it)

Comment: @Rekshino i moved codes to window.cs and now crash fixed but, expected behavior not work

Comment: Try to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and post new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code would be the equivalent of your XAML markup:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        RebuildBehavior behavior = new RebuildBehavior();
        BindingOperations.SetBinding(behavior, RebuildBehavior.ElementProperty, 
            new Binding() { ElementName ="Not" });
        Interaction.GetBehaviors(this).Add(behavior);
    }
}
```